# What does this getFirebaseRoot error occur on InterstitialAd?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, admob

Creating a react-native app and trying to ad ads through admob and firebase, but getting an error I couldn't find much on.

[image]

Relevant parts of my App.js:

```
...
import {
  InterstitialAd,
  TestIds,
  AdEventType,
} from '@react-native-firebase/admob';
...
showAds = () => {
    let interstitial = InterstitialAd.createForAdRequest(TestIds.INTERSTITIAL);

    let interstitialListener = interstitial.onAdEvent(type => {
      if (type === AdEventType.LOADED) {
        interstitial.show();
      }
    });
    interstitial.load();

    return () => {
      interstitialListener = null;
    };
  };

onEvent = e => {
    if (e.type === 'game-over') {
      this.setState({
        running: false,
      });
      this.showAds();
};
```

UPDATE:

Following [this guide](https://rnfirebase.io/#2-android-setup) instead but getting another error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah sorry to tell you but **@react-native-firebase/admob is now deprecated** The last supported version was 11.5.0. I wasted time with this too because this old website (https://rnfb-docs.netlify.app) says it exist. When really you should use this one (https://rnfirebase.io). What I did was used (https://www.applovin.com/) for ads it was really easy to setup.

Comment: Damn thanks! Been hitting my head on this for a few days. Gonna follow the guide in rnfirebase.io hopefully that will work.

Comment: I followed that guide but getting this error (added img in the original post above) when I run `npx react-native run-android`